# Rails Money migration fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I am trying to import all migrations. However, the use of `t.monetize :total, currency: { present: false }` within a create_table block seems to crash with the following error message:

```
class AddAddressAndOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.belongs_to :order
      t.integer :quantity, default: 0
      t.monetize :price, currency: { present: false }
      t.monetize :total, currency: { present: false }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)
```

Each time I get to a t.monetize (or t.money) column reference I receive the same error... added below (including --trace):

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate

== 20160901101357 AddAddressAndOrder: migrating ===============================
-- create_table(:orders)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)
schema_definitions.rb:311:in `column'
table_pg_rails4.rb:9:in `block in monetize'
table_pg_rails4.rb:6:in `each'
table_pg_rails4.rb:6:in `monetize'
/Users/Paul/folder/Sites/project/db/migrate/20160901101357_add_address_and_order.rb:20:in `block in change'
schema_statements.rb:282:in `create_table'
abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:363:in `create_table'
method_missing'
say_with_time'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `say_with_time'
`method_missing'
/Users/Paul/folder/Sites/project/db/migrate/20160901101357_add_address_and_order.rb:18:in `change'
`exec_migration'
migrate'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
migrate'
connection_pool.rb:408:in `with_connection'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:774:in `migrate'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `migrate'
execute_migration_in_transaction'
`ddl_transaction'
`execute_migration_in_transaction'
migrate_without_lock'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `each'
`migrate_without_lock'
migrate'
`with_advisory_lock'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1148:in `migrate'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
`migrate'
levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
`invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
top_level'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
top_level'
`run_with_threads'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
`standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)
schema_definitions.rb:311:in `column'
table_pg_rails4.rb:9:in `block in monetize'
table_pg_rails4.rb:6:in `each'
table_pg_rails4.rb:6:in `monetize'
/Users/Paul/folder/Sites/project/db/migrate/20160901101357_add_address_and_order.rb:20:in `block in change'
schema_statements.rb:282:in `create_table'
abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:363:in `create_table'
method_missing'
say_with_time'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `say_with_time'
`method_missing'
/Users/Paul/folder/Sites/project/db/migrate/20160901101357_add_address_and_order.rb:18:in `change'
`exec_migration'
migrate'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
migrate'
connection_pool.rb:408:in `with_connection'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:774:in `migrate'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `migrate'
execute_migration_in_transaction'
`ddl_transaction'
`execute_migration_in_transaction'
migrate_without_lock'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `each'
`migrate_without_lock'
migrate'
`with_advisory_lock'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1148:in `migrate'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@project/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
`migrate'
levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
`invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
top_level'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
top_level'
`run_with_threads'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
`standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/Paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

My Gemfile.lock looks like this regarding Money-Rails:

```
money (~> 6.10.1)
money-rails (1.10.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  monetize (~> 1.7.0)
  money (~> 6.10.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
```

The docs (https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#migration-helpers) state that this should be fine. So I've no idea what to do.

The issue seems to be within the `MoneyRails::ActiveRecord::Migration::Table.monetize` method:

```
module MoneyRails
  module ActiveRecord
    module MigrationExtensions
      module Table
        def monetize(accessor, options={})
          [:amount, :currency].each do |attribute|
            column_present, _, *opts = OptionsExtractor.extract attribute, :no_table, accessor, options
            column(*opts) if column_present
          end
        end

        # Removed for brevity
      end
    end
  end
end
```

No matter what is passed to monetize, it always seems to throw the same error. I really am lost as to what I am doing wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing anything in an initializer that might affect the `MoneyRails::Configuration#amount_column`? Looks like the `OptionsExtractor` is missing a few things.

Comment: You're right. My initializer for MoneyRails was overriding all amount column settings, not merging them, which was really dumb of me. Thank you for your help, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely the answer, it used to be that when you set "default_currency" to "gbp" it would set "postfix" to "_pennies". now it sticks to "_cents". Which means all our own columns still have "_pennies", so have to set postfix manually.